# Regular expression to return a number in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Hi i have a string and would like to search for the string that matches for example

[table id=345 /]

and would like it to return the digit 345. May I know what is the rule?

My rule is this:

```
preg_match("/\[table id=([^]*?) \/\]/s", $char, $match);
```

but not working.

How to get it return if there is more than one that match the pattern? at the moment it only return the first occurrence.

Comment: `\d` matches digits and `+` matches the preceding rule one or more times, so `(\d+)` is what you're looking for as opposed to `([^]*?)`. Also [here](http://www.regexr.com/) is a good place to test regular expressions.

Comment: FYI, just added a PHP online demo that prints all the matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match("@\[table ([0-9]+) \/\]@s",$char,$match);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your regex:

```
\[table id=\K\d+
```

This sample code prints all the matches (see output at the bottom of the [online dem](http://ideone.com/btEcol)o):

```
$string = "[table id=345 /] [table id=123 /]
[table id=999 /] [table id=000 /]";
$regex = "~\[table id=\K\d+~";
$count = preg_match_all($regex,$string,$m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

**Explain Regex**

```
\[                       # '['
table id=                # 'table id='
\K                       # Keep what has been matched so far out of the returned match
\d+                      # digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                         # the most amount possible))
```